# Weird Java replaceFirst

Tags: java, javascript, regex

What does this line mean?

```
str = str.replaceFirst("^\\s+", "")
```

I believe ^ must be a symbol for the beginning of line, but what is `\\s+` ? Is this just a string of characters or have some pattern meaning?

I am trying to convert this line to JavaScript.

Comment: I belive it is trying to trim all the leading whitespaces.

Comment: Thanks guys you give me hard time to choose the "right" right answer.

Comment: String s = "2+2=4";
    System.out.println(s.replace("+", "-"));
why is this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `\s` matches any whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, etc.)
- `+` means one or more of the previous character or character class.

So the pattern `str.replaceFirst("^\\s+", "")` matches any whitespace at the beginning of the string, and removes it.

The equivalent JavaScript would be `str.replace(/^\s+/, '')`.

Answer (score 2):

```
  str = str.replaceFirst("^\\s+", "")
```

is removing all the spaces at the begining of the string.

- `^` is used for beginning of the line
- `\\s+` is used for several white spaces

Answer (score 1):

`\\s+` is a regular expression.

To convert it to JavaScript is really simple.

```
str = str.replace(/^\s+/, '');
```